# Implicit and explicit Euler Method for expression of stochastic solutions in time T

Tags: numerical-methods, eulers-method

I have expression for implicit iteration (backward Euler Method):

$$X_{n+1} = X_{n}+\delta tX_{n+1}+\sqrt{\delta t}X_{n+1}Z_n,$$

where $n=0,...,N-1; Z_n iid\sim N(0,1)$

and explicit iteration (forward Euler Method):

$$X_{n+1} = X_{n}+\delta tX_{n}+\sqrt{\delta t}X_{n}Z_n.$$

I want to determine a solution formula for $X(T)$ for both expressions (implicit and explicit iteration) in the limit case $\delta t\to 0, T=N\delta t=const$.

How can i do this?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get to combine the factors of the infinite products in the resulting recursion formula via
$$
\prod(1+a_i)=\exp(\sum\ln(1+a_i))=\exp(\sum a_i-\frac12\sum a_i^2+\frac13 \sum a_i^3+...)
$$

Next you need to understand the chain of scales $δt\ll\sqrt{δt}\ll1$ to know which of the terms to keep, and then just expand the logarithms
$$
\ln(1-\sqrt{δt}Z_n-δt) ~~ \text{ resp. } ~~ \ln(1+\sqrt{δt}Z_n+δt)
$$
into power series. Then in the exponent the infinite products become infinite sums that can be seen as approximations of integrals.